# Can't assign roles from azure AD app manifest

Tags: azure, active-directory, manifest, roles

I was trying to implement role based authorization in my azure application  as described in the  http://www.dushyantgill.com/blog/2014/12/10/roles-based-access-control-in-cloud-applications-using-azure-ad/ article. Unfortunately, after I upload the manifest with the roles I can't assign the roles to the users - the assign button at the bottom of azure management portal is disabled (in the article, the action I want to perform is in the 4th screenshot). Has anyone encountered anything like that? Below is the appRoles part of my application manifest:

```
  "appRoles": [
    {
      "allowedMemberTypes": [
        "User"
      ],
      "description": "Can do some stuff",
      "displayName": "AU",
      "id": "c400a00b-f67c-42b7-ba9a-f73d8c67e433",
      "isEnabled": true,
      "origin": "Application",
      "value": "au"
    }
  ],
```

**Update**
Turns out, the reason the button was disabled was pretty simple - I have assigned the user previously and just assumed that if I implemented roles in the manifest, it would let me assign them via "Assign" button even though user has already been assigned.

Still, it doesn't solve the root issue - after removing the user from the app and assigning him once again the prompt with role assignment does not show up, user "Assigned" status simply changes to "Yes", as if no roles were set within the manifest.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, I should have figured it out sooner - the prompt for role assignment does not show up when there is only one role defined in the app manifest, in which case it automatically assigns the role to the user. I figured it when I looked through all the claims sent to the application and found my single defined role in there.

Dushyant Gill - thank you for the help.

Comment: Thank you for posting this exact question; I've been searching for this for a couple of days now. I'd made the same mistake w/ having just one role.

Answer (score 1):

jspi, only global administrators and user account administrators of the directory can assign users and groups to applications - can you confirm that the signed in user is in one of those two directory roles?

Comment: Yes, I try to do it signed in as a global administrator.

Comment: It looks like only the global administrators of the directory can assign users/groups to apps, but not user administrators. The latter one can only see existing users/groups, but not to assign.

Answer (score 0):

You have to refresh the Azure portal to see the change ( Click where it says Microsoft Azure ). You can also sign out and sign back in.
[image]